# How do I search and replace an entire multi-level array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace

How do I search and replace an entire multi-level array in PHP? As in something like:

```
$a = array(
  'level1' => array(
    'level2' => array(
      'level3' => 'foo'
    )
    'level2b' => array(
      'level3b' => 'foo'
    )
);
```

So, replace 'foo' with 'bar'.

BACKGROUND: I'm having to do this on a serialized array from a WordPress blog since we're moving this blog to another directory name.

Comment: why not create a function for that? I see you can do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple with [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-walk-recursive.php)

```
array_walk_recursive($a, function (&$val) {
  $val = str_replace('foo', 'bar', $val);
});

print_r($a);
```

Just make sure to use a reference (`&$val`).

**demo**: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7L33Fg

Comment: I just never had the need to do this before until now, and wasn't aware of the `array_walk_recursive()` function before. Awesome that you found that, and awesome that you knew of the `&$val` thing.